# Power shut off in the middle of an update

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, windows-update, updates, service-pack

I accidentally shutdown my PC in the middle of downloading SP1 from the Windows Update. After I booted my PC and tried to re-download SP1 again, it wasn't there. I tried looking for SP1 As an already-install update, but it's not there either. I tried to uninstall it through a CMD command, the message said that SP1 is not installed on my computer, so what should I do?

I haven't installed any updates before, and I do want to.

I only want SP1, that's all. Can anyone point me in right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can download the Win 7 SP1 update from the [Windows Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842) separately and then install it, rather than using Windows Update.

Comment: If that also fails, I would next try doing a "repair" install of the original version of Win 7 using the installation DVD in order to get your system back into proper shape to apply the SP1 update (however it's done). Just make sure your power doesn't go out again while you're in the middle of doing these things ;-).